# Single DAO or multiple DAOs in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, dao

In a one-to-many database mapping scenario, say one department can have multiple employees, what is the best practice to design the DAO layer?

Should I have one generic DAO class to get/set department object and get/set employees object or two separate DAO classes DepartmentDAO and EmployeeDAO to get/set department object and employee object respectively?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate it out with a dao for Department and another one for Employee. I think the red flag is: what would you call the combined dao?

If a clear and intuitive name doesn't arise in your mind immediately, it's a potential code smell. And if the name doesn't jump out at you, it will surely confuse other programmers who look at your code. Why stick two things together that are quite distinct?

Some guidelines:

1. If it were Employee and Contractor, for instance, I might give a little more credence towards combining them into a generic, but even then, it's somewhat likely I would keep them separate unless I had a strong reason to not separate them.
2. If your project starts getting huge with 15 or 20 DAOs, you may end up deciding to go to one DAO, but that's a decision you can make downstream. Then maybe you could make a HumanResources DAO or something like that. That's mainly just to prevent overabundant wiring.

There is very little downside to separating Department and Employee, and potentially a somewhat significant gain in clarity and ease of maintaining your code. And it isn't that hard to combine them in the future if you have a good reason to.

That's my take.

Comment: If the two classes have no relationship, it would be obvious to use two separate DAOs. I am using Hibernate for java class to database table mapping, and it has one-to-many relationship, so I was wondering if there would be any advantage to combine two DAOs together.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks to me like you would need at least 3 different DAOs:

- `DepartmentDAO`
- `EmployeeDAO`
- `EmployeeCollectionDAO`

Thing is - the mapping of single entity and mapping of group of entities has significant differences. Therefore, they should be handled by different structures, otherwise you have a risk of violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Also, the `Department` should be interaction with a collection of `Employee` instances, not with each instance separately.